# What programming languages can I assume on a random Linux server by default?

Tags: linux

There are many Linux distributions out there and all have different packages installed by default.

What languages are generally installed by default?

I know it is possible to install new packages but some admins do not like this.

Currently I would assume:
(Edit: I have added some answers. Thanks)

- Bash
- C (run but no compiling)

Often provided languages
 - Python
 - Perl

Tools (not languages)

- grep
- make
- sed
- yacc

Comment: add `awk` in your list

Comment: Python is quite common.

Comment: /bin/sh .. the best.   sed is also considered a "language".  With sh, awk, sed, you can rule the world.

Comment: the [POSIX environment](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/ape.html) docs mention the standard command line utilities like `grep`, `make`, `sed` and even `yacc`.

Comment: tcl is quite common too...

Comment: Even if particular languages are common, which *version* can vary greatly, particularly at times when major revision shifts are happening.  Even particularly minor shifts can cause problems, for example, relying on Python features new to 2.7 or 3.1.  PHP is a pretty common language to have on Linux servers too, at least any that run a web server.

Comment: Just as a side note, both `awk` and `sed` are Turing complete, and I have seem some moderately sophisticated programming done in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assume that Perl or Python are installed, even though they often are. For example, redhat-like distributions usually install Python, but other distributions commonly do not.

You should target specific distributions if this is a problem - or else you'll have to build your own (e.g. python) and ship it yourself - this is the only way of guaranteeing it's available. Actually if you are writing a nontrivial piece of software which needs to be portable to lots of distros, it's probably necessary to ship your own Python.

Comment: Debian-like distributions also install Python.

Answer (score 8):

The minimum you can expect to find on any unix system that's not antique or embedded is [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)/[Singe UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification). Specifically, all current unices mostly conform to [POSIX:2004, a.k.a. Single Unix issue 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/). This gives you `sh`, `sed` and `awk` as programming languages.

If development packages are installed (which they often aren't on a server), you can do development with `cc` (C compiler), `lex`, `yacc`, `make`; but apart from `make` these aren't useful on the machines you'll deploy your application to, only on development machines.

If you assume Linux, most distributions follow the [Linux Standard Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_standard_base) to some extent. The [LSB](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml) goes beyond POSIX. The [core specification](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/book1.html) includes a C runtime with support for multithreading, NSS, PAM, ncurses, libz, SSL and a few more libraries. The LSB doesn't require `bash`, only a POSIX `sh` which could be `ash` or `ksh`, but in practice most non-embedded Linux distributions ship `bash` as part of the default installation. The [languages specification](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Languages/LSB-Languages/book1.html) includes Perl and Python. In practice, not all distributions make full LSB support part of their default installation, but you can generally make a good case that if it's specified by LSB (but not in the LSB desktop specification, obviously), it should be installed on a Linux server.

On other systems, Perl is very often available. Python is not as common but gaining popularity. You can pretty much count on either `bash` or `pdksh` (but not always; IIRC NetBSD only has `ash` in its default installation). For compiled languages, you'll always find a C runtime and almost always find a C++ runtime.

Comment: A "C Runtime Library" can be described as "Any library that is linked to at run time [...]. Usually, though, the term is reserved for libraries that provide a language's basic interfaces ..." - hellos, http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/13399/

Answer (score 1):

Make and yacc may not be there.  Depending on whether or not you're on embedded systems, bash may not be there either.  Code to sh, and Perl if you want to go beyond that (I can't think of a single distro which doesn't come with Perl).

Comment: Very good point, Arch linux does not come with Make.

Answer (score 0):

As many others have already said, it depends on your distro. For example, if you have Fedora you probably have the following:

- C/gcc
- C++/g++
- perl
- python
- make
- and the standard Linux/Unix components

To find out what programming languages are on your system, type:
    man -k language
And to find out what utilities/tools/misc you have on your system, type:
    man -k name 
or:
    man name